# c# Serialize / Deserialize a Date without time

Tags: c#, date, momentjs

I have a server and I want to send a date without time. I send the date as string like `date.ToShortDateString()`. The clients read the date with momentjs: `moment(date, "DD-MM-YYYY").valueOf()`

The clients can change the date and with `momentjs` I send the date as string like `moment(date).format("DD-MM-YYYY")`.

Is this way rigt or should I consider the culture for a date without time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and send it to front-end if on there you didn't need time part.